# lua, combining strings with variables inside tables when imported from file

Tags: lua

I am having a problem with variables inside tables. this is essential since I use tables as configuration for my program.

so I have tested the following code that works:

```
> x = "X"
> t = {["ref"]="table with value: "..x}
> print(t["ref"])
table with value: X
> x = "Y"
> t = {["ref"]="table with value: "..x}
> print(t["ref"])
table with value: Y
```

it however doesn't work without the second `> t = ["ref"]="table with value: "..x`

now I went to implement this into my main program witch consists of two files, one witch returns the configuration table. And one file with all the functions and stuff. it looks as following

FILE A (main.lua):

```
testString = "test1"
print(testString)
local CONFIG = require'config'
print(CONIFG[1].test)
testString = "test2"
print(testString)
local CONFIG = require'config'
print(CONIFG[1].test)
```

FILE B (config.lua):

```
local CONFIG = {
           {["test"]=[[this is a test: ]]..testString}
          }
return CONFIG
```

now when i run file A (a.k.a. main.lua) i get the following output:

```
test1
this is a test: test1
test2
this is a test: test1
```

i can't figure out what i am doing wrong here.. i thought it had something to do with that it was a single string so i made `testString` a table but that gave me the same result...

(that title really seems scary.. sorry)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`require`, by design, caches the return value. So if you call `require` with the same string, it will not execute the script again. It will simply return the previously returned value.

`require` is for loading modules. And modules should not change their return values based on other global state.

The function you're probably looking for is `dofile`. This will always load and execute the file (but it has none of the path searching properties of `require`). Alternatively, you can use `loadfile` to load the file as a function, then execute that function to regenerate the table whenever you want.

Also:

> I am having a problem with variables inside tables.

There are no "variables inside tables". Or at least not the way you mean. Expecting a change to a variable to affect some other value is like expecting this:

```
a = 5
b = a + 5
a = 10
assert(b == 15, "This will never be true.")
```

When an expression (whether `a + 5` or `"table with value: " .. x`) is evaluated, it results in a value. The resulting value is in no way dependent on any value or variable from the expression that generated it.

That's why you had to regenerate the value; because values don't change just because some variable changes.

Comment: thank you very much.. i thought require executed the string when it was called... also "I am having a problem with variables inside tables." might have been a incorrect description.. i am sorry about that but thanks for your clarification :D

Comment: the program now works with the following code `local CONFIGf = assert(loadfile("config.lua"))` `local CONFIG = CONFIGf()` or `local CONFIG = assert(loadfile("config.lua"))()` if you like oneliners ;p